# Create a matrix with random numbers when required shape is derived from other variables

Tags: j

I want to create a matrix with random numbers  in J programming language when the required shape is derived from other variables.

I could create such a matrix with `? 3 5 $ 0` if i specify its shape using literal integers. But I am struggling to find a way to create such a matrix when the shape is `# y`  and `# x` instead of 3 and 5 shown in above example.

I have tried `? 0 $~ # y, # x` and it has not worked.

I think I need some way to apply `#` over a list of variables and return a list of numbers which should be placed after `$~`, somewhat like `map` functionality of other languages. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `?@:$` is what you are looking for

```
   3 5 ?@:$ 0
0.031974   0.272734    0.792653   0.439747  0.136448
0.332198   0.00904103  0.7896     0.78304   0.682833
0.27289    0.855249    0.0922516  0.185466  0.257876
```

The  general structure for this is `x u@:v y   <->  (u (x v y))` where u and v are the verbs and the arguments are x and y.

Hope this helps.

Rereading your question it looks as if you want the shape to be based on the number of items in the arguments. Here I would use `#` to count the items in each argument, then use `,` to create the left argument for `$&0` and apply `?` to the result.

```
   3 4 5  (?@:($&0 @:,))&#  5 3 3 4 5
0.179395  0.456545  0.805514  0.471521  0.0967092
0.942029  0.30713   0.228288  0.693909  0.338689
0.632752  0.618275  0.100224  0.959804  0.517927
```

Is this closer to what you had in mind?

And as often the case, I thought of another approach overnight

```
   3 4 5 ?@0:"0/ 1 2 3 4 5
 0.271366   0.291846  0.0493541  0.72488   0.47988
 0.50287    0.980205  0.58541    0.778901  0.0755205
 0.0114588  0.523955  0.535905   0.5333    0.984908
```

Comment: Built on Bob's approach but using a fork `3 4 5  (, ?@:$ 0:)&#  5 3 3 4 5`